# Ubuntu 19.10 login stuck on purple screen at login

Tags: boot, nvidia, login, multiple-monitors, 19.10

This is not a proper question but might be of help to someone with the same problem.

Every time Ubuntu updates system files under 19.10 I get a purple screen at login without the login prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the Nvidia card at boot switches to a hypothetical second screen, sets it as primary and shows only the blank secondary. When I move the mouse to the right, the mouse pointer appears coming from the left side of the screen - hence there is a second screen to the left of my laptop that I can't see. But I can access it, typing

Enter (My login password) Enter

and Ubuntu starts normally. the first time it happened it also showed me a blank desktop since also in GUI the primary desktop was the not-connected second screen. Changing the screen options on the laptop via shortcut (Fn - F5 or F6 in my case) restored the single screen. I the changed the screen options to single screen again and I'm safe until the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After reading the above answer, I noticed that I actually had plugged my monitor in twice (once with HDMI, once with displayport). Hence the blank purple screen I saw in place of the login screen was responsive to me typing in my password. Had been sat there for hours messing around with nomodeset etc and all kinds... this was a much easier solution!